# how to skip bad records in hadoop map-reduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata

i am very much new to hadoop,can any one give me a simple program on how to skip bad recors in hadoop map/reduce?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What do you mean by bad records?What's the criteria to decide that?

Comment: Do you mean if the input is corrupt? Then have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/14921893/1050422 . If an exception is thrown in your mapper/reducer, catch it, log it and you may also increment a counter specific for that error so that you can see the stats when the job finishes

Comment: if some values are missing in my record,i can say that particular record is a bad record,i want to skip that record instead of processing it and show that particular record is a bad record in the logs.

Comment: Corrupt record and bad record are 2 different things. If a value is missing how are you going to **skipping** it. By virtue of being absent it is automatically skipped. Could you please share some sample data with some more details? That would be really helpful.

Comment: @Tariq i was going through skipping bad records in hadoop definitive guide.here is the link to go https://www.inkling.com/read/hadoop-definitive-guide-tom-white-3rd/chapter-6/task-execution

Comment: @Tariq iam very much new to hadoop,trying to understand that topic and implement the same to see how it actually works.if you can put up your points,that would be really helpful for me.Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are filtering records based on missingness of fields, this is logic suitable for your Mapper implementation. A Java API Mapper could look something like this:

```
public class FilteringMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, LongWritable, Text>{

private static final Logger _logger = Logger.getLogger(FilteringMapper.class);

protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) {

    if(recordIsBad(value))
        _logger.info(<log record data you care about>);
    else
        context.write(key, value);

}

private boolean recordIsBad(Text record){
    //return true if record is bad by your standards
}

}
```

This Mapper would only filter based on your standards. If you need further transformations of data in the Mapper this is easily added.

Answer (score 1):

> The best way to handle corrupt records is in your mapper or reducer
>   code. You can detect the bad record and ignore it, or you can abort
>   the job by throwing an exception. You can also count the total number
>   of bad records in the job using counters to see how widespread the
>   problem is. In rare cases, though, you can’t handle the problem
>   because there is a bug in a third party library that you can’t work
>   around in your mapper or reducer. In these cases, you can use Hadoop’s
>   optional skipping mode for automatically skipping bad records.   When
>   skipping mode is enabled, tasks report the records being processed
>   back to the tasktracker. When the task fails, the tasktracker retries
>   the task, skipping the records that caused the failure. Because of the
>   extra network traffic and bookkeeping to maintain the failed record
>   ranges, skipping mode is turned on for a task only after it has failed
>   twice.
>
> Thus, for a task consistently failing on a bad record, the tasktracker
>   runs the following task attempts with these outcomes:
>
> 1. Task fails.
> 2. Task fails.
> 3. Skipping mode is enabled. Task fails, but failed record is stored by the tasktracker.
> 4. Skipping mode is still enabled. Task succeeds by skipping the bad record that failed in the previous attempt.
>
> Skipping mode is off by default; you enable it independently for map
>   and reduce tasks using the `SkipBadRecords` class. It’s important to
>   note that skipping mode can detect only one bad record per task
>   attempt, so this mechanism is appropriate only for detecting
>   occasional bad records (a few per task, say). You may need to increase
>   the maximum number of task attempts (via `mapred.map.max.attempts` and
>   `mapred.reduce.max.attempts`) to give skipping mode enough attempts to
>   detect and skip all the bad records in an input split. Bad records
>   that have been detected by Hadoop are saved as sequence files in the
>   job’s output directory under the `_logs/skip` subdirectory. These can
>   be inspected for diagnostic purposes after the job has completed
>   (using `hadoop fs -text`, for example).

Text from "*Hadoop: The Definitive Guide*" By Tom White

Answer (score 0):

You can skip records in your MapReduce job by setting the properties `mapreduce.map.skip.maxrecords` and/or `mapreduce.reduce.skip.maxgroups` to a value >0 (by default they're 0).

Here's a simple command that you can run on the shell using [Hadoop streaming](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-streaming/HadoopStreaming.html#Hadoop_Streaming) to launch a MapReduce job that is going to ignore 1000 mapper fails:

```
mapred streaming \
  -D mapreduce.map.skip.maxrecords=1000 \
  -file map.sh \
  -file reduce.sh \
  -input myInputDir \
  -output myOutputDir \
  -mapper map.sh \
  -reducer reduce.sh
```

(where `map.sh` and `reduce.sh` are executable bash scripts).

From the [documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.9.2/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html#Skipping_Bad_Records):

> Hadoop provides an option where a certain set of bad input records can
>   be skipped when processing map inputs. Applications can control this
>   feature through the [SkipBadRecords](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.9.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/SkipBadRecords.html) class.
>
> This feature can be used when map tasks crash deterministically on
>   certain input. This usually happens due to bugs in the map function.
>   Usually, the user would have to fix these bugs. This is, however, not
>   possible sometimes. The bug may be in third party libraries, for
>   example, for which the source code is not available. In such cases,
>   the task never completes successfully even after multiple attempts,
>   and the job fails. With this feature, only a small portion of data
>   surrounding the bad records is lost, which may be acceptable for some
>   applications (those performing statistical analysis on very large
>   data, for example).

You can see all properties related to skipping records in [`mapred-default.xml`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/mapred-default.xml).

Another relevant property is `mapreduce.task.skip.start.attempts`: the number of failed attempts before the MR task will start to skip records (default is 2).